# Error executing script in c# using CefSharp

Tags: c#, jquery, cefsharp

I try to use the next

```
chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('#user').setAttribute('value', 'usuario');");
```

I received the message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

When I use the console browser of Chrome it's successfully executed.

Comment: Are you executing that script before jquery.js is added to the page?

Comment: i'd avoid using jquery in this case. this is simple enough with the dom apis

Comment: i guess, when i use document.getElementbyId("user").value = "usuario" is working correctly but i need to use $("user") cause when i used getElementbyId the form returns me "user is required" although i gave the value

Comment: @DanielA.White exist another way to do that? im new with CefSharp

Comment: you might need to trigger a change event.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute your scripts after your dependencies has been loaded. On `browser.LoadingStateChanged` event, probably would be the best place for that.

Look at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript for more information.

Comment: i got the same message inside of LoadingStateChanged

Comment: Did the page included jQuery successfully? I mean, if you delay the script execution time enough, it executes successfully?